# How to remove parent category from child category url using wordpress rewrite rule?

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, terms, rewrite-rules

I am trying to remove parent category from the child category but nothing happens. I have a website made with the use of EDD. currently i have categories like below:

- angular-templates
- react-templates
- bootstrap-templates

In each categories, there are sub-categories/child-categories as below:

**angular-templates**

- angular-1
- angular-2
- angular-3

now if i go to my sub-category, url displays as below:

http://admin-pc/mysite/templates/category/angular-templates/angular-3/

And i want to remove angular-templates or whatever is the category name in url to remove and display url as below:

http://admin-pc/mysite/templates/category/angular-3/

Is it possible with add_rewrite_rule()?

I have achieved what i want with str_replace, but that will affect site's SEO, so that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any of the solutions work for you. There are a few ways we can try to achieve this.

[**Through WP Permalinks**](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/removing-category-base-urls-wordpress/)
    Go to Settings >> Permalinks and select Custom and enter: /%category%/%postname%/
    Next set your Category Base to .

**Through Yoast Plugin**
  Go to Yoast SEO
  Select advanced
  Click on the tab permalinks at the top
  Check Strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL

**[Use Remove Category Url Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/)**